# Showing the set $A = \{ x \in l_1 : |x_n| \leq 1/n^2 ,\forall n\}$ is closed

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Showing the set $A = \{ x \in l_1 : |x_n| \leq 1/n^2  ,\forall n \}$ is closed. I had to show it is compact, and I am done showing it is relatively compact, but now I am stuck showing it is closed.

$l_1$ is the space of finite sequences $x = (x_1,x_2,...)$ with the norm $\|x\|_1 = \sum_k^\infty |x_k| < \infty$ i.e. the set $A \subset l_1$ with sequences where each component of the sequence is bounded by $1/n^2$ for every component.

I done a lot of work to show it is relatively compact, so I feel as though showing it is closed should be simple - but I can't make any progress.

Any help please

Comment: Is that for all $n$?

Comment: Yes - I'll edit my original post.

Comment: How did you show it is relative compact without showing it's compact?

Comment: @zhw. I constructed a finite $\epsilon$ net for the set $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $c_1,c_2, \dots \in (0,\infty).$ Let $A = \{a\in l^1: |a(n)| \le c_n, n = 1,2,\dots\}.$ Then $A$ is closed in $l^1.$ Proof: Suppose $a_m$ is a sequence in $A$ such that $a_m \to a$ in $l^1.$ Because convergence in $l^1$ implies convergence in each slot, we have, for each $n\in \mathbb N, a_m(n) \to a(n)$ as $m\to \infty.$ But the limit of a sequence of real numbers, each of which is $\le c$ in absolute value, is itself $\le c$ in absolute value. It follows that $|a(n)| \le c_n$ for each $n,$ hence $a \in A.$ Thus $A $ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

First show that the set $A_k = \{x \in \ell_1 : |x_k| \leq 1/k^2 \}$ is closed. Then notice $A = \bigcap_{k \geq 1} A_k$  is the intersection of closed sets, hence closed.

For this, define $\pi_k : \ell_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\pi_k(x) = x_k$. It is pretty strightforward to show $\pi_k$ is continuous for all $k$. Then $A_k = \pi_k^{-1}([-1/k^2, 1/k^2])$ is the inverse image of a closed set, hence closed.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow, your $A_k = A$ here

Comment: Oh, in you $A$ the $n$ is fixed?

Comment: No, I've edited my original post sorry for the confusion.